# Ending a grid early with Flex-box and Foundation 6

Tags: sass, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I'm having issues trying to stop an element joining part of a grid in Foundation 6 using the Flex-grid. The markup is:

```
<section>
  <h2>A great headline</h2>
  <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</p>
  <a href="">Something</a>
</section>

section {
  @include flex-grid-row();
  h2 { @include flex-grid-column(12); text-align: center; }
  p { 
    @include grid-column-offset(3);
    @include flex-grid-column(6);
    text-align: center;
  }
  a {  }
}
```

I want the `a` tag to appear below the `p` but because the `p` only takes up 9 columns the `a` tag joins it.

In the standard grid you used to be able to use `@include grid-column-end;` but that obviously doesn't work now. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to wrap the `<p>` and the `<a>` in another container. The way it is now will apply display: flex on the section and all the immediate children will be flex children and therefor sit side by side by default.

[Example](http://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/ggwyaO)

Also, you do not need to offset columns if you are trying to center them. The .align-center class on the row can do it.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, still getting to grips with Flex. Was hoping to have to add anymore markup.